# error excel export data in odoo 8

Tags: python, excel, odoo

when i want to export my data i get this error [image]

i'm working on Windows 7 , i checked  my file "site.py "

```
def setencoding():
"""Set the string encoding used by the Unicode implementation.  The
default is 'ascii', but if you're willing to experiment, you can
change this."""
encoding = "ascii" # Default value set by _PyUnicode_Init()
if 0:
    # Enable to support locale aware default string encodings.
    import locale
    loc = locale.getdefaultlocale()
    if loc[1]:
        encoding = loc[1]
if 0:
    # Enable to switch off string to Unicode coercion and implicit
    # Unicode to string conversion.
    encoding = "undefined"
if encoding != "ascii":
    # On Non-Unicode builds this will raise an AttributeError...
    sys.setdefaultencoding(encoding) # Needs Python Unicode build !
```

Comment: User say `sys.setdefaultencoding(encoding)` but computer `OS` used `ASCII` , Locale is nothing on windows, try set `OS` default encodings..

Answer (score 0):

You have to set another encoding in `site.py` to use for example `utf-8`. The file states this:

> but if you're willing to experiment, you can change this.

So you could just change

```py
encoding = "ascii" # Default value set by _PyUnicode_Init()
```

to

```py
encoding = "utf-8" # Default value set by _PyUnicode_Init()
```

You also could use the windows locale for encoding by enabling the first if case:

```py
# Enable to support locale aware default string encodings.
```